# How can we calculate accuracy for the Random forest classifier if we are using 4 label classification?

Tags: python, random-forest

I am trying to predict the quality attributes of the product which have been sold over last decade.
Based on the likes/dislikes i have kept the 4 label for the product
Labels are: bad , good, very good,very bad

I have downloaded the last decade data and categorized the samples in these 4 labels. When i put the input in random forest classifier , it is giving the valid result and giving the feature importance:

Here is the code for same:

```
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(
        n_estimators=100, n_jobs=6, oob_score=True, random_state=50,
        max_features="auto", min_samples_leaf=50
    )
    '''

    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(
        n_estimators=100, n_jobs=6, oob_score=True, random_state=50#, max_depth=3
    )
```

I just want to understand , how we can calculate the accuracy of the model as it has 4 labels.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few accuracies you can check to assess model quality; the first is the overall model accuracy (how many did it get right). For this you can simply use the sklearn [accuracy score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Of course this is not giving you enough information about which class is being miss-classified and to what (eg. it might be more acceptable to categorize very good as good rather than bad). For this you need a [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

You probably also want to look into recall and precision as they will help understand the matrix and quantify it.
What you can also do since your labels are ranked, is to convert them to int values and adress the problem with a regression instead of a classification (then convert the outputs back to ints). This way the model will get an understanding of order, therefore you get an ordinal classification.

### EDIT:

Just in case the answer is not clear, you get `y_pred` in the following way:

```py
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_val)
```

Comment: Can you share a use case sample with 4 lable classificatio

Comment: I don't have a specific use case in mind atm, but the iris flowers classification is a good example generally speaking and you will find a few implementations for this eg. [this](https://www.codementor.io/agarrahul01/multiclass-classification-using-random-forest-on-scikit-learn-library-hkk4lwawu) and [here](https://www.kaggle.com/anthonyhills/classifying-species-of-iris-flowers)

Comment: I tried to calculate the accuracy and it was giving 37 &, I believe for any 4 label classification algo, accuracy can't ve more than 40 %, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Of course it can be more than 40%! if you get everything in the right class you still have 100% accuracy. In multi-class classification the accuracy is calculated as `(True_C1+True_C2+...+True_Cn)/Total_NSamples`. In a 4 class classification, your random accuracy is 25% (this is assuming balanced dataset) but you can improve much more than that

Comment: Yes, i do have a balanced dataset.

Comment: So you are performing better than random at the moment, but there is significant room for improvement in the model (37% is your baseline for now). Maybe try different/less/more features or a different classifier altogether!

Comment: Hey guys! I have a question about how to to see each label's accuracy?

Comment: @Megan the diagonal of the confusion matrix should give you the class accuracy